# what is the difference between JMS and XMPP?

Tags: jms, xmpp

It seems that xmpp is used as protocol in chat application, but JMS also support multiple receiver mode.

It seems that JMS is used in financial messaging system, but xmpp may also support persistence and reliable delivery.

Can someone give an overview of these two protocols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JMS is an API that you can use to send various types of messages to one or many other J2EE clients whereas streams XML elements as the means of communications.

JMS provides a loosely-coupled interaction between modules so you can send any object. XMPP is a network protocol that enables you to transfer any XML structure.

XMPP's most popular usage is instant messaging via Jabber, but it isn't constrained to that domain. JMS' most popular usage is abstract communication between applications.

I guess, JMS is more centralized as everything should pass through the JMS provider. However, XMPP is not centralized like  that.

JMS supports both one-to-one and one-to-many interactions, but XMPP is used mainly for one-to-one.However, this can be done through joining all these clients in a chat-room type of interaction.